# Adding property to object, defining it and immediately logging it returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Why does immediately invoking newly added property to the object return "undefined"? Going through the compiling and running process would be great. Example line 3 console.log:

```
function foo(baz) {
    this.baz = "baz";
    console.log(baz); //why does this print undefined?
}

var baz = new foo();
```

Comment: because it is, you'd need `this.baz`. you've declared a property of `foo`, not a global varaible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to use `this.baz` to access the variable you've added earlier.

`this` inside the `foo()` refers to the `foo` function. But, when you log `baz` it'll be searched on the `window`(global) object, since it is not defined in the `foo()`.

So, your statement is like:

```
console.log(window.baz);
```

Since `baz` is not defined, it'll log `undefined`.

**Demo**

```js
function foo() {
  this.baz = "baz";
  alert(this.baz);
}

var baz = new foo();
```

**Demo of global `baz`**

```js
var baz = 'foo';

function foo() {
  console.log(this);
  this.baz = "baz";
  alert(baz);
  // Same as alert(window.baz);
}

var baz = new foo();
```

---

**Updated question:**

> Sorry I forgot to add parameter. I've edited the question –  Nazerke

```
function foo(baz) {
    this.baz = "baz";
    console.log(baz); //why does this print undefined?
}

var baz = new foo();
```

Because you haven't passed any parameter to the `foo()` when creating new object using `new`, you get `baz` as `undefined` in the `foo()`.

**Demo**

```js
function foo(baz) {
  this.baz = baz;
  alert(baz);
}

var baz = new foo('Magic!');
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add parameter. I've edited the question

Comment: @Nazerke Check the Update in answer

Comment: Yes, we didn't pass anything. But aren't we defining it in the function, first line?

Comment: @Nazerke That is already answered in the first part of the answer. `Because you need to use this.baz to access the variable you've added earlier.

this inside the foo() refers to the foo function. But, when you log baz it'll be searched on the window(global) object, since it is not defined in the foo().`

Comment: this inside the foo doesn't refer to the function itself but to the object that is created by the virtue of constructor call. My question stems from the confusion related to the lexical scoping. In my understanding any inside function must be first searched in the function scope, and then, if not found, go out and search the global scope.In this case,we look for baz in the function first, and we are supposed to see that it is there and not "go out" to the global scope.